# how to validate a private message recipient when a user atempt to send message to another user or users

Tags: mysql, database

I'm developing an application in which users can send private message to each other.
Assume that a user want to send a message to users `David , jack, John`. Something that is clear I must validate this recipients and check if they exist in the `users` table.
but I don't have a clear scenario to do this job.

Should I prepare a query like:

```
select user form users where user_name=David OR user_name=Jack OR user_name=John
```

Then if row count was 3 let the user send his message and if not drop the action?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic as far as SQL questions go, so you really need to get a better reference for that sort of thing.

The type of query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT id, user_name FROM users WHERE user_name IN ('David','Jack','John')
```

Presumably you have an `id` column of some kind.

Remember to have an `INDEX` on the `user_name` field if you're making queries on it.